# Javascript change source of music

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I want to make my javascript to change the source of my html audio.
I searched on stackoverflow but ccould not find what I wanted.

This is my html code. I don't used css at this moment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>HigherLower</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1> welcome to my game. This game is about selecting if a number is getting higher or lower than the previous number.
    Click this button to get started.</h1>

  <audio id="currentsong" loop autoplay controls src="trol.mp3"></audio>

  <button id="songbutton" onclick="nextsong()">next song</button>


  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
    /**
  * Created by Jasper on 12-1-2017.
  */
 var currentsong = document.getElementById('currentsong');
 var nextbutton = document.getElementById('songbutton');

 currentsong = 1;
 currentsong = 2;
 currentsong = 3;

 function nextsong() {
   if (currentsong = 1) {

     innerHTML = currentsong.src = 'trol.mp3';
   } else {
     currentsong.innerHTML = currentsong.src = 'paradise.mp3';
   }
 }
```

I want to make the music change on a buttonclick. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change

`currentsong.innerHTML=currentsong.src='paradise.mp3';`

To

`currentsong.src = 'paradise.mp3'`

Comment: thanks for commenting. it still does not work... i see that i also made a mistake in my post. innerHTML=currentsong.src='trol.mp3'; has to be currentsong.src=trol.mp3, without the innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Here is something i you can try..however you need to fix your code as you are using the same variable as counter var on which you retrieve reference 
to your element 'currentsong'

```
var currentsong = document.getElementById('currentsong');
var nextbutton = document.getElementById('songbutton');

var currentsong_counter =1; //use a different counter here 
 currentsong_counter = 1;// not sure why you are doing consecutive assignments as it will get last value ie. 3
 currentsong_counter = 2;
 currentsong_counter = 3;

 function nextsong() {
   if (currentsong_counter === 1) {
     // if you want both html and source to changed then use below else currentsong.src = 'trol.mp3' will do the work
     currentsong.innerHTML = currentsong.src = 'trol.mp3';
    // 
   }  
   else {
     currentsong.innerHTML = currentsong.src = 'paradise.mp3';
   }
 }
```